# How to distribute opencv in an addon?

Tags: python

I would like to use the `cv2` contained in `opencv` (Below the example). I'm not sure if it can be done, the goal is to distribute it together with the addon.

I don't know how to start thinking. For example, the first thing that came to my mind, is to put the opencv folder directly in the addon folder. But this doesn't work when I import it into the script: `from ..opencv_4x.modules.python.package import cv2 as cv`

Give me this error:

```
ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation.
```

How can I use it in blender? Bearing in mind that deploying the addon must work on Win/Linux/Mac

Comment: it "should" work if you just use the same command in your add-on with e.g. "exec" as you did to install it on your computer.

Comment: Don't you want to use the PyPI distribution?